# Yahoo oauth not working with jasig Cas 4.0 java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, cas, jasig, yahoo-oauth

I am using jasig cas 4.0 with google oauth2 configured and working fine. I added yahoo1 bean in applicationContext.xml and then ${YahooClientUrl} in the casLoginView.jsp.

The link on the yahoo is :

```
http://127.0.0.1:47123/cas/login?client_name=YahooClient&needs_client_redirection=true
```

I noticed that clicking the yahoo link gives the error

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/rajan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/6edffc576ce104ec769d954618764f39f0f0f10d/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2014-11-23 15:47:13,477 INFO [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - <Loaded 1 services.>
2014-11-23 15:47:18,953 INFO [org.jasig.cas.util.AutowiringSchedulerFactoryBean] - <Starting Quartz Scheduler now>
2014-11-23 15:47:33,916 INFO [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - <Beginning ticket cleanup.>
2014-11-23 15:47:33,968 INFO [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - <0 tickets found to be removed.>
2014-11-23 15:47:33,974 INFO [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - <Finished ticket cleanup.>
2014-11-23 15:47:56,462 INFO [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction] - <Setting path for cookies to: /cas-fluffy/>
2014-11-23 15:48:14,273 INFO [org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.web.flow.ClientAction] - <requires http action : {}>
<RequiresHttpAction> | code: 302 |
    at org.pac4j.core.exception.RequiresHttpAction.redirect(RequiresHttpAction.java:50)
    at org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.getCredentials(BaseClient.java:131)
    at org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.web.flow.ClientAction.doExecute(ClientAction.java:142)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:535)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:366)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:222)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:140)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:193)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.github.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

The application is redirecting to yahoo successfully, asking for permission if I want to allow the application to grant access. Now while redirecting from yahoo to the login page, some more exception occurs and its redirecting to error page.

```
2014-11-22 21:01:55,937 ERROR [org.pac4j.oauth.client.BaseOAuthClient] - <Failed to get user data, code : 404 / body : <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-us"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Yahoo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimal-ui">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <style>
    html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        background: #fafafc url(https://s.yimg.com/nn/img/sad-panda-201402200631.png) 50% 50%;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font: 300 18px "helvetica neue", helvetica, verdana, tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
    }
    table {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border: none;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 42px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #400090;
    }
    p {
        color: #1A1A1A;
    }
    #message-1 {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #message-2 {
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
        max-width: 17em;
        _width: 17em;
    }
        </style>
    <script>
      document.write('<img src="//geo.yahoo.com/b?s=1197757129&t='+new Date().getTime()+'&err_url='+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+'&err=404&test='+encodeURIComponent('-')+'" width="0px" height="0px"/>');
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- status code : 404 -->
    <!-- Not Found on Accelerator: social.yahooapis.com -->
    <!-- host machine: r34.ycpi.bf1.yahoo.net -->
    <!-- timestamp: 1416669419.000 -->
    <!-- url: http:///v1/me/guid?format=xml-->
    <table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>
        <img src="https://s.yimg.com/nn/img/yahoo-logo-201402200629.png" alt="Yahoo Logo">
        <h1 style="margin-top:20px;">Will be right back...</h1>
        <p id="message-1">Thank you for your patience.</p>
        <p id="message-2">Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>


    </body></html>
    >
    2014-11-22 21:01:56,132 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
    =============================================================
    WHO: audit:unknown
    WHAT: supplied credentials: [org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.authentication.principal.ClientCredential@f50e1d]
    ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
    APPLICATION: CAS
    WHEN: Sat Nov 22 21:01:56 NPT 2014
    CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 10.0.2.2
    SERVER IP ADDRESS: 10.0.2.15
    =============================================================

    >
    2014-11-22 21:01:56,146 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
    =============================================================
    WHO: audit:unknown
    WHAT: Failed to retrieve data / failed code : 404 and body : <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-us"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Yahoo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimal-ui">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <style>
    html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        background: #fafafc url(https://s.yimg.com/nn/img/sad-panda-201402200631.png) 50% 50%;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font: 300 18px "helvetica neue", helvetica, verdana, tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
    }
    table {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border: none;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 42px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #400090;
    }
    p {
        color: #1A1A1A;
    }
    #message-1 {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #message-2 {
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
        max-width: 17em;
        _width: 17em;
    }
        </style>
    <script>
      document.write('<img src="//geo.yahoo.com/b?s=1197757129&t='+new Date().getTime()+'&err_url='+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+'&err=404&test='+encodeURIComponent('-')+'" width="0px" height="0px"/>');
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- status code : 404 -->
    <!-- Not Found on Accelerator: social.yahooapis.com -->
    <!-- host machine: r34.ycpi.bf1.yahoo.net -->
    <!-- timestamp: 1416669419.000 -->
    <!-- url: http:///v1/me/guid?format=xml-->
    <table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>
        <img src="https://s.yimg.com/nn/img/yahoo-logo-201402200629.png" alt="Yahoo Logo">
        <h1 style="margin-top:20px;">Will be right back...</h1>
        <p id="message-1">Thank you for your patience.</p>
        <p id="message-2">Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>


    </body></html>

    ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_NOT_CREATED
    APPLICATION: CAS
    WHEN: Sat Nov 22 21:01:56 NPT 2014
    CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 10.0.2.2
    SERVER IP ADDRESS: 10.0.2.15
    =============================================================

    >
    /cas-fluffy/login
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.web.flow.ClientAction@1a3163 in state 'clientAction' of flow 'login' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
        at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:60)
        at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77)
        at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
        at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
        at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:535)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:366)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:222)
        at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:140)
        at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:193)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:125)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.github.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:63)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
    Caused by: org.pac4j.core.exception.HttpCommunicationException: Failed to retrieve data / failed code : 404 and body : <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-us"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Yahoo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimal-ui">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <style>
    html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        background: #fafafc url(https://s.yimg.com/nn/img/sad-panda-201402200631.png) 50% 50%;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font: 300 18px "helvetica neue", helvetica, verdana, tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
    }
    table {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border: none;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 42px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #400090;
    }
    p {
        color: #1A1A1A;
    }
    #message-1 {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #message-2 {
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
        max-width: 17em;
        _width: 17em;
    }
        </style>
    <script>
      document.write('<img src="//geo.yahoo.com/b?s=1197757129&t='+new Date().getTime()+'&err_url='+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+'&err=404&test='+encodeURIComponent('-')+'" width="0px" height="0px"/>');
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- status code : 404 -->
    <!-- Not Found on Accelerator: social.yahooapis.com -->
    <!-- host machine: r34.ycpi.bf1.yahoo.net -->
    <!-- timestamp: 1416669419.000 -->
    <!-- url: http:///v1/me/guid?format=xml-->
    <table>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>
        <img src="https://s.yimg.com/nn/img/yahoo-logo-201402200629.png" alt="Yahoo Logo">
        <h1 style="margin-top:20px;">Will be right back...</h1>
        <p id="message-1">Thank you for your patience.</p>
        <p id="message-2">Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>


    </body></html>

        at org.pac4j.oauth.client.BaseOAuthClient.sendRequestForData(BaseOAuthClient.java:226)
        at org.pac4j.oauth.client.YahooClient.retrieveUserProfileFromToken(YahooClient.java:79)
        at org.pac4j.oauth.client.YahooClient.retrieveUserProfileFromToken(YahooClient.java:43)
        at org.pac4j.oauth.client.BaseOAuthClient.retrieveUserProfile(BaseOAuthClient.java:149)
        at org.pac4j.oauth.client.BaseOAuthClient.retrieveUserProfile(BaseOAuthClient.java:43)
        at org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.getUserProfile(BaseClient.java:147)
        at org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.getUserProfile(BaseClient.java:52)
        at com.fluffy.cas.authentication.ClientAuthenticationHandler.doAuthentication(ClientAuthenticationHandler.java:63)
        at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.java:78)
        at org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.authenticateInternal(PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.java:211)
        at org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.java:143)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
        at com.github.inspektr.audit.AuditTrailManagementAspect.handleAuditTrail(AuditTrailManagementAspect.java:126)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
        at org.perf4j.aop.AbstractTimingAspect$1.proceed(AbstractTimingAspect.java:47)
        at org.perf4j.aop.AgnosticTimingAspect.runProfiledMethod(AgnosticTimingAspect.java:53)
        at org.perf4j.aop.AbstractTimingAspect.doPerfLogging(AbstractTimingAspect.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.authenticate(Unknown Source)
        at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.createTicketGrantingTicket(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:531)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
        at com.github.inspektr.audit.AuditTrailManagementAspect.handleAuditTrail(AuditTrailManagementAspect.java:126)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
        at org.perf4j.aop.AbstractTimingAspect$1.proceed(AbstractTimingAspect.java:47)
        at org.perf4j.aop.AgnosticTimingAspect.runProfiledMethod(AgnosticTimingAspect.java:53)
        at org.perf4j.aop.AbstractTimingAspect.doPerfLogging(AbstractTimingAspect.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.createTicketGrantingTicket(Unknown Source)
        at org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.web.flow.ClientAction.doExecute(ClientAction.java:161)
        at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
        at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
        ... 44 more
    2014-11-22 21:02:28,554 INFO [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - <Reloading registered services.>
    2014-11-22 21:02:28,558 INFO [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - <Loaded 1 services.>
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the Chairman of CAS and founder of CAS in the cloud (https://www.casinthecloud.com). I'm the creator of the pac4j library as well.

It seems that Yahoo returns a 404 error page instead of getting the user profiel. It says: "Will be right back...". Does it work now?

Comment: No it does not work. I have been trying it for almost a week. Jasig cas 4.0.0 with pac4j 1.4.0. It is not working.

Comment: The endpoint now requires HTTPS, which has been changed in pac4j 1.6: try that... https://github.com/leleuj/pac4j/blob/master/pac4j-oauth/src/main/java/org/pac4j/oauth/client/YahooClient.java#L87

Comment: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not find org.scribe:scribe:1.3.6.
  Searched in the following locations:
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.pom
      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.jar
      http://treelogic-swe.com/maven_repo/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.pom
      http://treelogic-swe.com/maven_repo/org/scribe/scribe/1.3.6/scribe-1.3.6.jar
  Required by:
      :cas-fluffy:0.1 > org.pac4j:pac4j-oauth:1.6.0

Comment: scribe is in a dedicated repository: https://github.com/leleuj/pac4j/blob/master/pom.xml#L56

Comment: As soon as I click the link to authenticate from Yahoo, the console throws the following error(even in https + pac4j 1.6.0)
2014-12-13 11:58:18,015 INFO [org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.web.flow.ClientAction] - <requires http action : {}>
<RequiresHttpAction> | code: 302 |
 at org.pac4j.core.exception.RequiresHttpAction.redirect(RequiresHttpAction.java:50)
 at org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.getCredentials(BaseClient.java:131)
 at org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.web.flow.ClientAction.doExecute(ClientAction.java:142)
 at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188

Comment: This is not an error, just an INFO saying that a redirection to Yahoo is required.

Comment: I get the following error with pac4j1.6 with jasig cas 4.0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.pac4j.core.client.Client.getRedirectionUrl(Lorg/pac4j/core/context/WebContext;)Ljava/lang/String;
 at org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.web.flow.ClientAction.prepareForLoginPage(ClientAction.java:197)
 at org.jasig.cas.support.pac4j.web.flow.ClientAction.doExecute(ClientAction.java:168)
 at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)

Comment: pac4j 1.6 is not compatible with CAS server v4.0.0, it will be with CAS server v4.1.0. In your case, you need to inherit a new FixedYahooClient from the current YahooClient and change the endpoint using HTTPS.

Comment: seems like yahoo does not support custom ports as well in the redirect url.